# How do I clean up my workerThread after calling quit on it?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have a function which when is called creates a new thread called workerThread. It basically sends a network request and in the else block below, I have handled the case where a network error  has occured. I am unsure whether in the below code if the error is occured and the code in the else block executes, will the workerThread that I created be cleaned. If it wont, then how can i clean the workerThread?

```
if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError){
    /* Some Code */
} else {
                qDebug() << "Error:" << reply->errorString();
                QMessageBox::critical(this, "Error", reply->errorString());
                workerThread->quit();
                return;
     }

QObject::connect(workerThread, &QThread::finished, workerThread, &QThread::deleteLater);
```

Comment: Important note: QThread is not a thread. It is a thread _controller_. The QThread lives in the thread where it is createdn(typically main GUI thread)  not in the thread it controls (runs the event loop for). In other words, when the controlled thread is not running yet/any more, it's just an idle QObject instance.